# Google Maps API - transparent pass through address components

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a web-form with a text area where a user can type in an address. I need the form not only to store the formatted address (which is currently working) but also transparently pass through the address components for storing in a backend database.

The current code below predicts the possible addresses as the user types:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;key=*******************"></script>


*** snip ***

<script>
    function init() {
        var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'NZ'
            }
        };
        var input = document.getElementById('streetAddress');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);     <-- autocomplete is never used?
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
  </script>


*** snip ***

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="streetAddress" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetAddress" placeholder="Street Address" name="location"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am assuming I need to call a second google function - geocoder which after onClick which returns a geocoded address array from the address string in the function above.

I could then store its components in hidden html form input elements unless there is a better way.

Thymeleaf and spring-boot are being used to get the data into the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to add some elements to your page that are hidden to store and pass through the address.

The example below passes through the street number - you can expand it from there. The HTML & Thymeleaf:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="streetAddress" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetAddress" placeholder="Street Address" name="location" th:field="*{formattedAddress}" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="streetnumber" th:field="*{streetNumber}" /> <!--hidden-->
    </div>
```

Now the javascript:

```
var options = { componentRestrictions: { country: 'NZ'  } };
var input = document.getElementById('streetAddress');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);


autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place.address_components[0].short_name);
var streetNumber = document.getElementById("streetnumber");
streetNumber.value = place.address_components[0].short_name;
});
```

Error handling needed.